# Pattern fails when a space is missing between two consecutive groups or for the very first group

Tags: python, regex

I would like that the following pattern gives the same result for all the `finditer` uses. I need to find unescaped `\g`, this is why I use `(?:[^\\])`.

```
import re

p = re.compile(r"(?:[^\\])\\g<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z\d_]*)>")

for m in p.finditer(r"</\g<name_1>\g<name_2>\\g<escaped>>"):
    print(m.group(1))

print('---')

for m in p.finditer(r"</\g<name_1> \g<name_2>\\g<escaped>>>"):
    print(m.group(1))

print('---')

for m in p.finditer(r"\g<name_1>\g<name_2>\\g<escaped>>"):
    print(m.group(1))
```

Here is the corresponding output where `name_2` is missing in the first output, and `name_1` is missing in the last one.

```
name_1
---
name_1
name_2
---
name_2
```

Why the use of a space makes the two groups always findable ? How to do a starting alternative with the interdiction group or the starting of the text `^` ? How to change my pattern to avoid this failures ?

Comment: I'm more concerned what this does `[a-z|A-Z|_][a-z|A-Z|_|\d]*` ? It's a character class, so you shouldn't add `|` for an alternation. You do that in groups `()`. Anyways, it would become `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z\d_]*` or more simplified `[a-zA-Z_]\w*`. And if you want it shorter `[^\W\d]\w*` :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. Indeed, I'm french and I do not want to catch decorated letters, so this is the reason of the use of `a-zA-Z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is pretty close, but it requires that the sequence start with some non-backslash character:

```
[^\\]
```

This string:

```
</\g<name_1>\g<name_2>>
```

has one sequence starting with a non-backslash (`/`) that continues on to read `\g<` as required, but following that is a sequence that does *not* start with a non-backslash followed by `\g<` (it immediately dives into having a `\g`).  Adding a space makes it work as the space provides the necessary non-backslash character.

You could augment your pattern to make the initial non-backslash character optional:

```
p = re.compile(r"(?:[^\\])?\\g<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z\d_]*)>")
```

but since the parentheses here are the non-grouping `(?:...)` variety, it's simpler to just remove the entire parenthesized expression:

```
p = re.compile(r"\\g<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z\d_]*)>")
```

The resulting regular expression works with your sample inputs.

---

Edit: to address the requirement that `\g<` not be preceded by a backslash, use "negative look-behind":

```
p = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)\\g<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z\d_]*)>")
```

The string being "checked to make sure it's not there" must be fixed length, and the single character `\` is.  If the search is running at the beginning of a string, negative look-behind permits the match; if it's in the middle, it "looks behind" to make sure the parenthesized fixed-length sub-expression is not present.

Comment: I've updated my question because I nedd the use of `(?:[^\\])` so as to only find unescaped `\g`. Sorry for not having pointed this before.

Comment: Ah, in that case you want "negative lookbehind" (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).  Will update.